# Best practice reading newest rows from database

Tags: mysql, django, postgresql

I have a table which stores the location of my user very frequently. I want to query this table frequently and return the newest rows I haven't read from.

What would be the best practice way to do this. My ideas are:

1. Add a `boolean` read flag, query all results where this is false, return them and then update them ALL. This might slow things down with the extra writes
2. Save the id of the last read row on the client side, and query for rows greater than this. Only issue here is that my client could lose their place
3. Some stream of data

there will eventually be multiple `users` and `readers` of the locations so this will not to scale somewhat

Answer (score 1):

If what you have is a SQL database storing rows of things. I'd suggest something like option 2.

What I would probably do is keep a timestamp rather than in ID, and an index on that (a clustered index on MSSQL, or similar construct so that new rows are physically sorted by time). Then just query by anything newer than that.

That does have the "losing their place" issue. If the client MUST read every row published, then I'd either delete them after processing, or have a flag in the database to indicate that they have been processed. If the client just needs to restart reading current data, then I would do as above, but initialize the time with the most recent existing row.

If you MUST process every record, aren't limited to a database, what you're really talking about is a message queue. If you need to be able to access the individual data points *after* processing, then one step of the message handling could be to insert into a database for later querying(in addition to whatever this is doing with the data read).

Edit per comments:

If there's no processing that needs be done when receiving, but you just want to periodically update data then you'd be fine with solution of keeping the last received time or ID and not deleting the data. In that case I would recommend not persisting a last known id/timestamp across restarts/reconnects since you might end up inadvertently loading a bunch of data. Just reset it max when you restart.

On another note, when I did stuff like this I had good success using MQTT to transmit the data, and for the "live" updates. That is a pub/sub messaging protocol. You could have a process subscribing on the back end and forwarding data to the database, while the thing that wants the data frequently can subscribe directly to the stream of data for live updates. There's also a feature to hold onto the last published message and forward that to new subscribers so you don't start out completely empty.

Comment: FYI, I highly recommend delete after processing over a column flag. Simply because the table is going to get bigger and bigger, so having an ongoing process read/update it is going to get slower and slower.

Comment: I need the data for historical data so I don't want to delete it. Is that an issue?

Comment: Also I did NOT need to process every record, if I lose my place and skip some that is fine. Its just for animating an object over a map.

Comment: Option 2 is good if you don't mind some risk of missing rows. It's possible for a row with a lower ID to commit after a row with a higher ID, so the client sees 1, 2, 3, 5 - then 4 commits after the client fetches it. The client will ask for > 5 next time, so it'll never see 4.